# twilio keyword response python search incoming body

Tags: python, twilio

Can someone help to see what went wrong or suggest improve code to search through the incoming sms body to send different responses?

```
from twilio.twiml import TwiML

    @app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'post'])
    class MessagingResponse(TwiML):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MessagingResponse, self).__init__()
            self.name = 'Response'
        def sms_reply():
        for letter in message:
            if letter  == 'hello':
                Response("Hi!")
                break
        elif letter == 'bye':
            Response("Goodbye")
            print(res)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/JULE3Tmi

Comment: Paste your code in the question and format it.